# CakePHP Pagination of associated HABTM model in Model View Controller

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I have two models - products and categories
Category model HABTM Product

When I create a View controller to view a single category, my recursive is set to 1 so I can load products in that category. Which is simple, works fine.

But, how can I paginate and/or sort ONLY the products within the category. I've tried three or four different approaches but none leaves me with what I would expect - paginated products I can pass to the view to create a grid of sorted/paginated products.

Here is the controller, all standard stuff:

```
//CATEGORY CONTROLLER
public function view($id = null) {


    $category = $this->Category->find('first', array(
        'recursive' => 1,
        'conditions' => array('Category.id' => $id)
    ));

    if (empty($category)) {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'), 301);
        $this->Session->setFlash('The category could not be found.');
    }
    $this->set(compact('category'));

    // paginate products and make them available to view -- ???



}
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

In the [Pagination documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html), search for the following text

> name the keys of the array after the model you wish to configure

This covers how to handle multiple and/or 'other' models. In brief, you want something that looks like:

```
// CategoriesController::view()
$this->paginate = array(
    'Product' => array(
        'conditions' => array('Product.category_id' => $category_id)
    ),
);
$products = $this->paginate('Product');
$this->set(compact('products'));
```

Note the conditions are now arranged under a key named 'Product'.

Comment: So thanks for the response ... but if you take another look at my question, it wasn't how to paginate the products from the products controller. It was how to paginate the products from the products loaded from **CATEGORIES** controller, where the categories HABTM products. Maybe I wasn't as clear on that, code marked up now.

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as to another question asked here.
Solution: [how to get books from one category excluding other category (through cross table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394429/how-to-get-books-from-one-category-excluding-other-category-through-cross-table#answer-13406919)

Combine the linking model with the pagination and you are done. You just filter by product_id instead of category_id after you fetched all the regarding products.
Using the linking model for pagination finding should work, too. Never tried it though. Just test it ;)

Greetings
func0der