# how to get books from one category excluding other category (through cross table)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

For now I am using following code to get books from certain category:

```
$options['conditions']['Category.id'] = $category_id;
$options['joins'] = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'books_categories',
        'alias' => 'BookCategory',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array('Book.id = BookCategory.id_book'),
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'categories',
        'alias' => 'Category',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array('BookCategory.kat = Category.id'),
    ),
);

$this->Book->find('all',$options);
```

This just finds all books from given category_id.

So there are 3 tables: `categories`,`books` and `books_categories`. books_categories has two fileds: `book_id` and `category_id` so basicly its just HABTM relation. The problem is that one book may belong to many categories and I want for example find all books from category 5 but excluding books from categories 5,6 and 7. How I can do this?

edit -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Ok so I figured out how it should look in pure SQL - the conditions should be like this:

```
where
  category_id = <given category>
  and books.book_id not in
(
 select book_id from book_categories
  where category_id in (<given set of cat>)
)
order by books.inserted
```

this will get all books from one category but excluding books from a set of other categories.
Now I want to force Cake to generate similar SQL query.
I tried so far:

```
$options['conditions']['Category.id'] = $category_id;       
$options['conditions']['AND'][] = 'Book.id NOT IN (SELECT id_book FROM book_categories WHERE kat IN (133,134))';

$options['order'] = array('Book.inserted' => 'desc');
$options['joins'] = array(
            array(
                'table' => 'book_categories',
                'alias' => 'BookCategory',
                'type' => 'inner',
                'conditions' => array('Book.id = BookCategory.id_book'),
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'categories',
                'alias' => 'Category',
                'type' => 'inner',
                'conditions' => array('BookCategory.kat = Category.id'),
            ),
        );
```

This generates this query (sory - table names are little bit different):

```
SELECT `Book`.`id`, `Book`.`OK`, `Book`.`price`, `Book`.`link`, `Book`.`title`, 
`Book`.`author`, `Book`.`img`, `Book`.`inserted`, `Book`.`checked`, `Book`.`big_img`, `Book`.`lang`, `Book`.`asin`, `Book`.`description`, `Book`.`last_update`, `Book`.`review`, `Book`.`changed` 
FROM `amazon`.`linki` AS `Book` 
inner JOIN `amazon`.`cross_kategorie_full` AS `BookCategory` ON (`Book`.`id` = `BookCategory`.`id_book`) 
inner JOIN `amazon`.`kategorie` AS `Category` ON (`BookCategory`.`kat` = `Category`.`id`) 
WHERE `Category`.`id` = 4 
AND `Book`.`OK` = 'OK' 
AND ((`Book`.`big_img` NOT LIKE '%no-image%') 
AND (`Book`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT id_book FROM cross_kategorie_full WHERE kat IN (133,134)))) 
ORDER BY `Book`.`inserted` desc LIMIT 20
```

But there is error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded - so There is something that doesnt end (loop?) in this sql statement...

Comment: You have to run this query using the mysql command from a shell. The timeout is because your're running it via a php script (am I correct?)...

Comment: Now, this query optimization problem is another question altogether :) You are aware that you are running `NOT IN (SELECT id_book FROM...` for every single record? (as I subtly hint in my answer). That's another join my friend!

Answer (score 1):

*Update relative to updated question* 
For the sql to yield correct results (in an acceptable time) you'll need to join with `Categories` again giving it another alias. Since this leads to another question, I suggest you post it tagged with `mysql` and `query-optimization`.
*End update*

As it is, a **HABTM relationship is a bit devious** (since it really isn't a HABTM). If you have only one row per book-category match in `books_categories` you can't know to what other categories a certain book belongs to, so you can't really tell which ones you really want (i.e. don't belong in those other categories). It's CakePHP's data layer and models that solve this problem for you behind the scenes :)

The only solution I see is to use [`Set::extract`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set%3a%3aextract) to further query the results that you get  and filter out Books that belong to Categories that you didn't want to include. (something like:

```
// returns all books not belonging to categories 3,4
$new_result = Set::extract('/Books/Category[id!=3][!=4]', $results);
```

On a side note, I find it very useful in cases like this, to query the DB and visualize the complexity of the SQL query that gets you the required results. Also, you should activate the CakePHP debug toolbar to see the SQL queries that are sent to the DB so you have a better idea of what's going on behind the scenes.

The CakePHP book, advises the following at the end of ["Associations: Linking models together"](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set%3a%3aextract) Section (emphasis mine).

> Using joins allows you to have a maximum flexibility in how CakePHP handles associations and fetch the data, however *in most cases you can use other tools to achieve the same results* such as correctly defining associations, binding models on the fly and using the Containable behavior. *This feature should be used with care* because it could lead, in a few cases, into bad formed SQL queries if combined with any of the former techniques described for associating models.

Comment: But if I want paginate the results I will get for example 20 books - then I use `Set::extract(...)` and I have less than 20 books - how I can overcome this?

Comment: Pull some more from the db (say, another 20) extract what you need, merge with previous set, limit to 20.

This isn't a "smart" solution, but what you need to do is not standard either.

OTOH you can also "execute" a query directly on the db.

Comment: I updated my question - now I know how to do it  in SQL but I have to do it in CAKE.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in there. You want to get all books from category 5 but not from category 5, 6 and 7?

Nevermind. Cake convensions state out that there should be always a primary key within the HABTM table, so you may add a "id" column. With this the next steps are much easier or should I rather say: "They are getting possible".

What you do next is, you create an association model called "BooksCategory".
Use the 'with' index explained here to link your Book and Category models with each other over that new model. Don't forget to use plugin syntax (PluginName.ModelName) in case the linking model belongs to a plugin.
You are now putting two belongsTo associations in the linking model for each of the models you are linking. This makes sure to fetch those while finding.

Next thing you do is:

```
$this->Book->BooksCategory->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'BooksCategory.category_id' => 5
        )
    )
);
```

Finished ;) No you get only the books from category 5.

Greetings
func0der

Comment: This is not the problem. Let's say book belongs to category 1,2 and 3. I want all books from category 1 but not from category 2 and 3. Book may have many categories...

Comment: Do you want books that are ONLY in category 1 but NOT! in cat 2 or 3?

Comment: yes - anyway the solution in my updated code works ok but only if num of elements in set is 1. I there are two or more elements it works extremly slow... like 15 seconds on query

Comment: PLace an index on all fields that are conditional fields (in WHERE and ON while joins). This should speed it up.
You can do this with cakephp too by using 'NOT' index in the conditions array.